# Ant taskdef resource="genjar.properties" doesn't work with Java 8

Tags: java, ant, jar, build

I am a newbine in ant build. My project is using ant taskdef resource="genjar.properties" to generate the jar. This work fine until we upgrade to java 8 and add some new Java 8 syntax code. The ant build is failed. I tried to replace the Java 8 with Java 7 syntax, the build success. This is 10 years old project, the MyApp.jar contains many classes so that switch to use jar is very hard. Could you suggest ideas about this problem?

The details error:

```
Build failed: Building MyApp.jar failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2925
at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:539)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:380)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask$CatchBlock.execute(TryCatchTask.java:138)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask.execute(TryCatchTask.java:224)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
Caused by: build.ml:497: Build failed: Building MyApp.jar failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2925
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Exit.execute(Exit.java:139)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:378)
... 17 more
--- Nested Exception ---
build.xml:497: Build failed: Building MyApp.jar failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2925
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Exit.execute(Exit.java:139)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:378)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask$CatchBlock.execute(TryCatchTask.java:138)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask.execute(TryCatchTask.java:224)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
```

Comment: What is the output of `ant -version`?

Comment: The ant version is 1.8.2